# Extract text from clicked submenu item of Menustrip

Tags: vb.net, menustrip, subitem

I've been dealing and looking for a way of extracting the text of any given subitem when clicked and write the text in textbox1.

this is the code that I have so far, but it does not seem to work.

```
Private Sub MenuStrip1_ItemClicked(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs) Handles MenuStrip1.ItemClicked

    Dim result As String

    If AccionAToolStripMenuItem.Checked = True Then
        result = AccionAToolStripMenuItem.Text
        TextBox1.Text = result
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong event. The ItemClicked event works for the items on the menu. You need to add a event for each of the subitems:

```
Sub SomeToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SomeTSMenuItem.Click
    TextBox1.Text = Ctype(sender, ToolStripMenuItem).Text
End Sub
```

You can make a function for each subitem or handle every event on the same function:

```
Handles item1.Click, item2.Click, item3.CLick
```

Comment: Thanks a lot SysDragon. Works great!

Comment: @user2065407 Please mark the answer as correct if thats the case.

Answer (score 0):

Try reading `e.ClickedItem.Text`.

Comment: Thanks Teejay, I've tried that but the thing is that I need the text of any given subitem; that is returning the text of the Item.

Comment: For example: The Item File has subitems like Open, Close, etc... I need those Open & Close texts...

Comment: @SysDragon has the correct answer. Sorry I misunderstood your request.